# MySQL query: How to also include matches with opposite direction?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written
query for displaying source to destination cost that will be
retrieved from database. But how to write a query that will additionally return same cost when I reverse my source and destination in the select box?

```
String sql="select * from USER where (source='"+name+"' AND
destination='"+name1+"')";
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: well, first of all this appplication is vulnerable for SQL injections, better use prepared statements.

Comment: Yea sure.Thanks for your suggestion:) @BalusC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `or`

```
select * from USER where (source='"+name+"' AND
destination='"+name1+"') or (source='"+name1+"' AND
destination='"+name+"')";
```

As i commented:

Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: Thank u.It worked.And I will surely take your suggestion:) @Jens